# Error While Configuring pydev in eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, user-interface, pydev

I am trying to configure Pydev in Eclipse. Even PYTHONPATH with python.exe file and downloaded wxpython package as well to interact with GUI environment

But, getting an error when i am starting python console in the "console" environment in Eclipse

Am wandering about "Thread_IsMain" error

AttributeError: module 'wx' has no attribute 'Thread_IsMain' Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\Software\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_5.8.0.201706061859\pysrc\pydevconsole.py", line 194, in process_exec_queue     inputhook()   File "D:\Software\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_5.8.0.201706061859\pysrc\pydev_ipython\inputhookwx.py", line 117, in inputhook_wx3     assert wx.Thread_IsMain()  # @UndefinedVariable

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue in PyDev itself when dealing with wx... maybe wx broke that API.

You can try just commenting out that line and checking if other things work -- as that code in the debugger is pure python, you can tweak it in place ;)